# Angular 4 Route Parameter Validation

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a route with a parameter userID

```
{
    path: "edit/:userID",
    component: EditUserComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
```

and on the edit-user-component.ts

```
    this.requestID = this.route.snapshot.params.requestID;
        this.formService
          .getPendingRequest(this.requestID)
          .subscribe((form: any) => {
            form.forEach(element => {
              if (element) {
                this.editRequest.patchValue({
                  userID: element.userID,
                  userName:element.username,               
});
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(["view"]);
              }
```

Now I have unique ID for every user. like I can visit **localhost:4200/edit/12** but if I go to **localhost:4200/edit/13** which does not exist in my mongoDB I want them redirect the page to 404 or main homePage.

Comment: Sounds like a [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) would meet your need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can check it the id returns 404 you can redirect to that page.

```
this.formService.getPendingRequest(this.requestID).subscribe(form => {

    }, error => {
        if (error['status'] === 404) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
    });
```

Comment: works! I had to make some changes on my backend! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You already know the concept:

1. You are using there in the `canActivate` with `AuthGuard`. Just implement another route guard in a similar way and in the constructor() get the Router object injected. This will give you the route parameters. Use this parameter to check if the data exists.
2. Use the angular resolver and if the data fails to exist at the given id, simply redirect from there itself and return a reject promise to cancel the current navigation.